# Mongoose find element $in nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mean

I have a schema with a nested array:

```
var QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  answers: [{
    answeredBy : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    answer: { type: String, trim: true, required: true }
  }],
  ...
});

export default mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

Now i want to find all questions that were answered by one specific user.

I tried it like

```
var userId = req.user._id;

Question.find({
      answers.answeredBy: {$in: userId}
    })...
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Does anybody have some clues for me please?

Comment: I think this might be the right way `answers: { $in : [{answeredBy: userId}] }`. Is that right?

Comment: You need `answers: {$elemMatch:{answeredBy: userId}}` and if you expect to have like thousands of answers you might want to create another collection for answers with ref to question